# Check previous step in shell script run trough Cron

Tags: linux, shell, shell-exec

--- file makebackup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE='date'
mysqldump --all-databases | gzip -9 > /backup/temp_db.gz
tar -Pcf /backup/temp_ftp.tar /public_html/
tar -Pcf /backup/temp_backup.tar /home/temp_db.gz /backup/temp_ftp.tar
sleep 60 && /backup/upload.sh $DATE
```

--- file upload.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# connect via scp
spawn scp /backup/temp_backup.tar root@mybackup.com:/home/backup_$argv.tar
#######################
expect {
-re ".*es.*o.*" {
exp_send "yes\r"
exp_continue
}
-re ".*sword.*" {
exp_send "mypassword\r"
}
}
interact
```

Why this does not work,  i don't want to use sleep i need to know when last tar is over and execute file upload.sh. Instead it always executes as soon as last tar file starts.

&& does not do anything even if i remove sleep 60

Comment: Looks like a good one for http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say 'Instead it always executes as soon as last tar file starts', normally that means there is an '&' at the end of the line OR are you sure the tar is really working? Are you looking at an old tar.gz that was created early on? Make sure it is a new tar file that is correct size.
**Edit** I'm not saying you have to delete files, just dbl-check that what is being put into the final tar makes sense.

Are you checking the sizes of input files to your final tar cmd? (/home/temp_db.gz /backup/temp_ftp.tar)? **Edit** By this I mean, that an uncompressed tar file (temp_ftp.tar) should be just slightly larger than the sum of sizes of all files it contains. If you know that you have 1 Meg of files that compose temp_ftp.tar, and the file is 1.1 Meg, that is good, if it is .5 Meg, then that is bad. (Also consider gziping the whole thing to reduce transmission time to your remote host). Your compressed db file, hard to say, presumably that is working, if the file size is something like 25 bytes, then that indicates an error in creating the file.

Otherwise what you are saying ***really*** seems impossible. It is one of these things, or something else is bollixing things up.

One way to debug how long the last tar is taking is to wrap the command in two date commands, i.e.

```
date
tar -Pcf /backup/temp_backup.tar /home/temp_db.gz /backup/temp_ftp.tar
rc=$?
date

printf "return code from quick tar was ${rc}\n"
```

Also, per your title, 'check previous step', I've added capturing the return code from tar and printing the value.

Again, to reinforce what you know already, in a linux shell script, there is no way (excepting a background job with the '&' char) for one command to start executing before the previous one has completed.

**EDIT** ownership and permissions on your files might be screwing things up is ownership and permissions on your files. use \

```
ls -l  /backup/temp_backup.tar /home/temp_db.gz /backup/temp_ftp.tar
```

to confirm that your userID owns the files and and that you can write to them. If you want to, edit your posting to include that information.

---

Also, your headline says 'cron' : are you capturing all of the possible output of this script to help debug the situation? Turn on shell debugging with `set -vx` near the top of makebackup.sh. Add debugging output to your tar cmd '-v'.

Capture the cron output of your whole process like

```
59 23 31 12 * { /path/to/makebackup.sh 2>&1 ; } > /tmp/makebackup.`/bin/date +\%Y\%m\%d.\%H\%M\%S.trace_log
```

And be sure you don't find any error messages.

( Crontab sample, min hr day mon (day-of-week, 0-6 or *) , change date/time to meet your testing needs)

---

Your expect script uses '\r', don't you want '\n' in the Unix/linux environment. If you're a Windows based server, then you want '\r\n' .

**Edit** does the expect script work, have you proved to your satisifaction that files are being copied, are they the same size on the backup site, does the date change?

---

If you expect backups to save your systems someday, you have to develop a better understanding of how the whole process should work and if it is working as expected. Depending on your situation and availability of alternate computers, you should schedule a test of your restoring your backups to see if they will really work. As you're using -P to preserve full-path info, you'll really need to be careful not to overwrite your working system with old files.

To summarize my advise, double-check everything.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am not good at linux script to begin with. Content of the file including top part (#!/bin/bash) are all here. "upload.sh" is something i found online.
I did not delete old files before starting scripts i thought there no need, i will try with deleting them. 
What do you mean if i check input size of files for final tar command, i would not know what size they should be as files on my website increase every day or is there something else you mean?

Comment: Size of my temp_ftp.tar is ~500mB indeed file archive file create good no error i deleted them at beginning of script and i do delete them in beginning of script now

Comment: Did check the debug info it does not give any more info its just temp_ftp.tar created then, upload.sh finishes in 2 seconds after tar finished which is not true because it takes about 10-20 seconds for it to really finish when run by hand or manually. 

Can someone test this on his system and see if you get same results?

I it does work when i jsut run ./makebackup.sh so i dont understand why it does not work from cron, in cron user shown as root too.

Comment: I"ll look at this sometime this weekend. Good luck.

Comment: you wrote 'upload.sh finishes in 2 seconds after tar finished ... because it takes 10-20 secs...' What size of file **is** created on the remote host? Good luck.